# CAN NOT figure out how to install opencv for Python

Tags: python, opencv, package, python-module

I'm brand new to using Python, and I have no background in C++, etc. (just a bit of SQL, SAS, and R), so I truly have no idea where to start with this.  I have tried running the cv2 module (import cv2) from both Canopy and Python(X,Y) with no luck (no module found error).  I know that the latter, if not both programs, are supposed to come with opencv pre-loaded, so I don't know what the issue is (other modules work fine).

I have researched this thoroughly on google, but either I don't understand the explanations due to lack of familiarity with python, or the solutions do not work for me.

Does anyone have any insight on what to do here?  Particularly using Canopy or Python(X,Y).  I will need an explanation in the most basic terms, as using a program such as Python is new to me.

Comment: Try [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which always worked for me and which i prefer to Canopy and Python(x,y). (I even use it on Linux despite the fact that it's easy there to compile opencv from sources if one has some experience)

Comment: opencv is not available by default with Canopy (you have to install it from their package manager); and only comes with the paid version of Canopy, so if you are using Canopy express you won't have access to opencv. Python(x,y) also doesn't come with opencv installed. You have to install it manually. So - to start off with, tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Anaconda doesn't appear to come with opencv either...is there an easy way to add it to the environment?

Comment: Which version of Python? For 2.7, just download the OpenCV distributable from their website, it contains both 32 and 64 bit Python modules. The just put the appropriate `cv2.pyd` somewhere Python will find it.

Comment: I put cv2.pyd in the site-packages folder of python 2.7 but I'm returning the same error.  Any other places you could think to put it?